# HTML input value disappears after adding jquery datepicker option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have multiple text inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" value="11-11-2016">
```

And the jquery script:

```
  $(".datepicker").each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
    $(this).datepicker("option", "changeYear", true);
  });
```

The input value disappears immediately after the page loads!!!

If I remove the option:

```
$(this).datepicker("option", "changeYear", true);
```

... the value doesn't dissapear, but whenever I add any of the jquery datepicker options - the value dissapears!?

Comment: @bresleveloper Please stop bothering people for plunkers or jsfiddles. The code has to go **in the question**, not on an external code hosting service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem it's in your initialization, try this:

```
$(function(){

    $('.datepicker').each(function(){
        $(this).datepicker({"changeYear": true});
    });

});
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/1804/)

Comment: According to the [official documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-changeYear), you can add the option after the initialization. I want to use that method for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this line afterwards to rectify the issue:

```
$(".datepicker").each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
    $(this).datepicker("option", "changeYear", true);
    $(this).attr("value", "11-11-2016");
});
```

If the attributes are dynamic per `$(".datepicker")`, then use the following:

```
function getElemAttributes(var element) {
    var attrs = {};
    var attrMap = element.attributes;

    $.each(attrMap, function (i, e) { attrs[e.nodeName] = e.nodeValue; });

    return attrs;
}
```

to get all of the attributes as an object. So:

```
$(".datepicker").each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker();

    // Returns something like { id: "datepicker", ..., value: "11-11-2016" }
    var originalAttributes = getElemAttributes(this);

    // Do stuff that affects attr on element.
    $(this).datepicker("option", "changeYear", true);

    // Set element attributes from riginal attributes object.
    if (originalAttributes.hasOwnOroperty("value")) {
        $(this).attr("value", originalAttributes["value"]);
    }
    else {
        // Didn't originally have a "value" attribute - set some default here?
    }
});
```

Comment: First I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var`, after I remove `var` I get `Uncaught TypeError: originalAttributes.hasOwnOroperty is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

You should use this option to set the initial date:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
```

in you code example:

```
  $(".datepicker").each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
    $(this).datepicker("option", "changeYear", true);
    $(this).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
  });
```

Comment: When I use this with `$(this).val()` instead of the date you made up, I get wrong date because of the format (I used "11-11-2016" in my value). If I first set the format option, the value disappears ... again.

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.datepicker').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
    $(this).datepicker("option", "changeYear", true);
    $(this).datepicker( "setDate", $(this)[0].getAttribute('value') );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This command helped me with the problem like yours:

```
let date = $(this.dateInput.nativeElement).val().toString();
....
$(this.dateInput.nativeElement).datepicker().val(date).trigger('change');
```